# $(element).height vs $(element).css('height',value);

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
function adjustHeight(){
            var headerHeight=$(element).find('.header').outerHeight();
            console.log(headerHeight);
            var temp=$(window).height()-headerHeight;
            console.log(temp);
            $('.users').height(temp);
        }
```

calling it once initially and on window resize

height of the .users element is always 30 px more than what is consoled temp variable.

```
        $('.users').css('height',temp+'px');
```

This works fine as expected.

```
<div class="mainPage" data-bind="visible:mode() === 'authenticated',handleHeightOfElements:''">
    <div class="header">
        <div>
            This is header text
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mainBody">
        <div class="users">

            All users:
            <div data-bind="foreach:userList">
                <div class="user">
                    <span data-bind="text:$data.userName,css:{onlineUser:$data.online()}">
                    </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

```
.users{
float: left;
width: 140px;
background: antiquewhite;
padding: 15px;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: Can you set up an example displaying the behavior?

Comment: `padding:15px` will add an padding of 15px on the top and the bottom. 15 + 15 = 30. `.height()` sets the innerHeight of an element. So the padding from your css will be added to this value.

Comment: Have a look at [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/nwcydn8r/). Try running ot with and without the `padding` in the css section and inspect the element `.user`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: `.css("height")` and `.height()` are equivalents.

But you set `$('.users').height(temp)` with `temp` which is the result calculation of `$(window).height()` minus `('.header').outerHeight()`

[`.outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/) includes padding, margin and border of the element.

This is not the case of `.css("height")` or `.height()`.

I bet your 30px offset comes from margin/padding/border.
And it fits with your last edit `padding: 15px;` for `.users`.

**EDIT**
Here is your calculation error imaged:

[image]

Darkened parts are not taken in account in your calculation.

Comment: There is no padding or margin in .header element, and in .users element i am using box-sizing:border-box , thats it shouldn't  affect anything.

Comment: @rishabhdev he is right. Your `.users` - div has a padding.